# Serving a react build version using nodejs express

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy

I am serving a react application using express server.I set up react application using proxy for api requests. I get a 404 error now that I am serving the react build using Nodejs. API routes are no longer working.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api/v1"

app.use(express.static('frontend/build'))
const path = require('path')
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default route should redirect to your static assets, not attempt to serve them.

```
app.use(express.static('frontend/build'))
// register other routes here
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})
// Wildcard catch other routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/frontend/build')
})
```

Comment: I can now only do post request. Am now getting internal server error

Comment: Infact the response data is html

Comment: I updated the answer for clarity on where to register your other api routes